# How to use case statement for os level versioning

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to write a script which basically gets executed according to the os version..This is what i did till now..

```
#!/bin/bash
publicyum="yum.oracle.com"
osrelease0=`lsb_release -r | awk {'print $2'}`
osrelease1=`lsb_release -r | awk {'print $2'}`
arch=`uname -p`

wget -q --spider http://$publicyum

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then

case $osrelease0 in
                '5')  ;;
                '5.1')  ;;
                '5.2')  ;;
                '5.3')  ;;
                '5.4')  ;;
                '5.5')  ;;
                '5.6')  ;;
                '5.7')  ;;
                '5.8')  ;;
                '5.9')  ;;
                '5.10)  ;;
                '5.11)  ;;
esac

if [ "$osrelease0" = "$osrelease0" ]; then
                echo "Success01"; uname -nm
        else
                echo "Failure01"
        fi

case $osrelease0 in
                '6')  ;;
                '6.1')  ;;
                '6.2')  ;;
                '6.3')  ;;
                '6.4')  ;;
                '6.5')  ;;
                '6.6')  ;;
                '6.7')  ;;
                '6.8')  ;;
                '6.9')  ;;
                *) echo "Non-Supported OS Version...Aborting!!!"
                exit 1;;
esac

if [ "$osrelease0" = "$osrelease0" ]; then
                echo "Success02"; uname -nm
        else
                echo "Failure02"
        fi

else
    echo "Internet is not accessible, Aborting!!"
fi
```

Below are the cases which i am trying to achieve:-

- The script should get executed as per the os version, Script should lookout for specific versions hardcoded in the script ex rhel 5-5.11 & rhel 6-6.11 and should execute certain commands
- Once the script reaches to if else loop it should look for certain arch x86_64/i686 and execute commands

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Guys any help is appreciated..

Comment: The if statements does not make sense. You need `==` to compare strings and you have `$osrelease0` on both sides of the equal-sign. Start by fixing that.

Comment: And it's better to use this form `osrelease0=`$(lsb_release -r | awk {'print $2'})` instead of back-quotes

Comment: Thnks nifle for the response, its still not working for me.

Comment: Thanks nifle for the response, its still not working for me.

code: https://www.pastiebin.com/58c12fc6d4ba8

Basically script should check for current os level and then should go to the case statement and should check if that version exist in the list. If yes, then success or else failure..Could you please  help me fix this?

Comment: You never assign a value to `osrelease1`, your case statement does nothing and you never do anything with the result of the call to wget.